# HTML entities with application/xhtml+xml Content-Type

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

When using the application/xhtml+xml Content-Type I cannot use any named HTML entities in my javascript ( , €, etc.).

It works fine when I use a text/html Content-Type. The offending HTML entities also work fine when put in the document itself (Instead of using Javascript).

When I hit the "F12 developer tools" in IE9, I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12) 
    javascript.js, line 7 character 2
XML5645: The specified entity has not been declared. 
    , line 1 character 42
```

Firefox gives a similar error:

```
[11:19:33.491] undefined entity:1
[11:19:33.493] uncaught exception: [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "http://arp242.net/entity-test/javascript.js Line: 8"]
```

And then execution stops.

I created a test page for testing/isolating where the problem is: http://arp242.net/entity-test/

As far as I can figure out, named HTML entities are perfectly valid in XHTML (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#h-A2)

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve the problem? I can enter the characters (€, —, “, ”, etc.) or numeric &#..; values and that works, but I'd rather use HTML entities. There is also quite a bit of existing (3rd party) code which uses HTML entities and I'd rather not convert all of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML hasn't text named entities, you can define them either in doctype or replace text named entities with char code entites ( eg. &nbsp; is &#160; etc. )

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
( Take unicode code point in decimal )

Comment: Yes, but in this case IE seems to broke or ignore it

Comment: Probably ignoring it. There's a warning somewhere about not depending on named entities since you need a DTD processing parser (or special case rules) to handle them.

Comment: I would expect a web browser to have special knowledge of the XHTML DTDs and to be able to use the entities from them appropriately. This is presumably the case since the OP says "The offending HTML entities also work fine when put in the document itself (Instead of using Javascript)." However, I wouldn't necessarily expect a browser to read the custom DTD present in the HTML page, which redeclares nbsp.

Comment: It would seem you're right after all. I put this on the backburner for a while, but I submitted a firefox bug report last week, and according to them it's how is "should" be ... I'm not so sure to be honest since the XHTML spec (As linked in the question) says something different as I understand it ... Ah well, here is the relevant report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=445166 (Mine was marked as a dupe of this one)...